# How to Avoid Soggy Chopped Nuts in Baked Goods

Tags: baking, nuts

I avoid putting chopped nuts inside quick breads because they tend to result in a soggy texture, not crisp as nuts should be. (I think it's less of a problem in cookies.) I'd like to hear how others deal with this. Is coating them first with something an option?

Related question: if I toast nuts in the oven, am I better off toasting them whole and then chopping, or chopping first and then toasting?

Answer (score 3):

Relating to your second question: toast, then chop. When you chop first, it is too easy for the smaller pieces to burn.

Comment: For the first question, if you toast the nuts before adding them it also helps with the texture. Coating in flour also helps with keeping the texture by giving the dough some anchorage and ensures even distribution.